# Combining different kinds of Observables in RxJS but only emitting values coming from one of them

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a BehaviorSubject, and two EventEmitters. I need to create an Observable that returns the latest value of the BehaviorSubject every time there is a new value emitted by the BehaviorSubject or there is an Event emitted by any of the EventEmitters. Basically, I don't care about the value of the event being emitted by the EventEmitters, they should just be a trigger to push out the latest value of the BehaviorSubject.

Here is an example:

```js
import Rx from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'
import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'

const bSubject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject('value1');
const emitter1 = new EventEmitter();
const emitter2 = new EventEmitter();

// Should I be using something othere than merge to create the Observable?
// Is merge ok but I should be using a special operator?
const myOberservable = Rx.merge(bSubject, emitter1, emitter2)

myOberservable.subscribe({next: value => console.log(value)});

emitter1.emit('event1');
bSubject.next('value2');
emitter2.emit('event2');
bSubject.next('value3');

/**
 * It prints:
 *  value1
 *  event1
 *  value2
 *  event2
 *  value3
 * 
 * But I want it to print:
 *  value1
 *  value1
 *  value2
 *  value2
 *  value3
 */
```

Comment: `merge(subject, merge(emitter1, emitter2).pipe(withLatestFrom(subject, (event, value) => value)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine `merge`, `withLatestFrom` and `map`. BTW I've updated snippet to enable tree-shaking.

```
import { merge, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { withLatestFrom, map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'

const bSubject = new BehaviorSubject('value1');
const emitter1 = new EventEmitter();
const emitter2 = new EventEmitter();

const merged = merge(bSubject, emitter1, emitter2);
const myOberservable = merged.pipe(withLatestFrom(bSubject), map(x => x[1]));

myOberservable.subscribe({ next: value => console.log(value) });

emitter1.emit('event1');
bSubject.next('value2');
emitter2.emit('event2');
bSubject.next('value3');
```

Comment: I was just playing around with this solution but it prints `value1 value2 value3` not `value1 value1 value2 value2 value3`. I don't quite understand why because according to the docs, it should be emitting everytime the notifier emits a value.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I wasn't aware that `sample` doesn't duplicate source emissions. I'll update my answer

Comment: Didn't know about `withLatestFrom`. This solution is even better than mine!

Comment: Thanks @AmitB. yeah, rxjs is full of surprises. Take for example https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/expand I wonder when I'll find use of it

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a perfect case of `switchMap`. I had to use `startWith` because of the way `switchMap` works, which only subscribes to the inner `Observable` once the outer `Observable` emits a value, therefore you wouldn't actually subscribe to `bSubject` until `emitter1` emits the first value. To overcome that, I used `startWith` which provides an initial value for the `Observable`.

```js
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const initialValue = 'value1';
const bSubject = new BehaviorSubject(initialValue);
const emitter1 = new EventEmitter();
const emitter2 = new EventEmitter();

const myOberservable = merge(emitter1, emitter2).pipe(switchMap(() => bSubject), startWith(initialValue));

myOberservable.subscribe({next: value => console.log(value)});

emitter1.emit('event1');
bSubject.next('value2');
emitter2.emit('event2');
bSubject.next('value3');

/**
 * It prints:
 *  value1
 *  value1
 *  value2
 *  value2
 *  value3
 */
```

For further reading, refer to [this](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html).